# How do I use coreclr_create_delegate to obtain a reference to a method generated at runtime?

Tags: c#, c++, .net-core, scripting

So I've got a c++ application to which I would like to add C# scripting to by way of .Net Core.

I've followed various tidbits around the internet and have cobbled together something that very broadly works.

I have found an initial approach:

Without giving the, rather verbose, code from the c++ app, here instead is some rough pseudocode.

```
    [PseudoCode]
    Establish location of 'coreclr.dll'
    LoadLibraryExA against 'coreclr.dll'
    GetProcAddress 'coreclr_initialize' and 'coreclr_create_delegate'
    Build TPA list (trusted platform assemblies) 
    call coreclr_initialize - getting hostHandle and domainId
```

This all works very nicely.

Given a C# assembly in the right folder, I can then reach out and grab a reference to a static method using...

```
    typedef void (*ptr_SimpleVoidProc)();
    ptr_SimpleVoidProc ptr_simpleVoidProc = nullptr;
    ...
    void** ptr;
    coreclr_create_delegate(hostHandle, domainId, "MyDiskAssembly","MyClass","MySimpleVoidProc", ptr);
    ptr_simpleVoidProc = reinterpret_cast<ptr_SimpleVoidProc>(ptr);
```

Then I can execute this code.

```
    ptr_simpleVoidProc();
```

Now imagine that I have another method in my C#....

```
    static void CompileCode(string code, string newAssemblyName)
    {
        SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
        
        ... // Sorts out references for new assembly here.
        
        CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                                            newAssemblyName,
                                            syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
                                            references: references.ToArray(),
                                            options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            EmitResult emitResult = compilation.Emit(ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

We can get a reference to the 'CompileCode' method from C++.

```
    typedef void (*ptr_CompileCode)(const char* code, const char* assemblyName);
    ptr_CompileCode ptr_compileCode = nullptr;
    ...
    void** ptr;
    coreclr_create_delegate(hostHandle, domainId, "MyDiskAssembly","MyClass","CompileCode", ptr);
    ptr_compileCode = reinterpret_cast<ptr_CompileCode>(ptr);
    ...
```

Which means I can compile code like so...

```
    ptr_compileCode(R"(
                            public class Script1 
                            {
                                public static void TestVoid()
                                {
                                    System.Console.WriteLine("TestVoid!");
                                }
                            }
                            
                    )", "MyGeneratedAssembly"
                    );
```

Next I should be able to get a c++ reference to the compiled method.

```
    ptr_SimpleVoidProc ptr_generatedVoidProc = nullptr;
    ...
    void** ptr;
    coreclr_create_delegate(hostHandle, domainId, "MyGeneratedAssembly", "Script1", "TestVoid", ptr);
    ptr_generatedVoidProc = reinterpret_cast<ptr_SimpleVoidProc>(ptr);
    ...
```

However ptr_generatedVoidProc (and indeed ptr) is null.

So why is it I can reach out and grab a reference to the static method which was present from the start ...
... but not apparently get one for the dynamically constructed code.

Have I done something wrong, or is this just not possible?

If it's not possible, is there some good reason why?

Might we consider this a bug, or should it not be allowed?

Many thanks for any help. I am happy to address any questions, or fill in any details.